# Fabric doesn't update my latest build version

Tags: ios, google-fabric

My fabric was working fine with previous versions whenever I tried to archive and submit to Appstore. However, I just submitted my latest build version and the fabric website doesn't have my latest build version but it does appear in the fabric Mac app. What should I do to get the latest build in Fabric website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. A version will show up in your Crashlytics dashboard when we've seen a run of that version with Fabric enabled. A new version may not show up on the Latest Release page until that version is used by 10% of all DAU (Daily Active Users) over the past 30 days or 4% of your DAU for the current day.

Comment: yea thanks for the help, my latest version has shown up in latest release page.